# React Native Css Not Working

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I use react native to create a form with CSS. But the CSS code is not working. How can I fix this?

http://prntscr.com/iz00xh 
http://prntscr.com/iz01m5  
http://prntscr.com/iz02qx

Result:

https://prnt.sc/iyxii3

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and [mcve]. This will help you get the answers you want.

Comment: Images of code are not accessible. Please copy your relevant code, edit the question, and use the code snippet tool to add it.

Answer (score 1):

To to make use of `Flex`
give `flex: 1` or `flex: 2` its definitely solve your issue. 
if you still face problem then try to give platform specific style.

For flex reference [check to read react native doc.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html)